# How to use TFL Api and get's its key?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-application, transport

I am currently building an iOS application which involves journey planning and travel updates etc, I am having a really difficult time finding TFL api key. Which I can use for my App, can someone please be kind enough to help me through it and guide who shall I contact.

Answer (score 0):

This question remains unanswered in SO for past two years.. I think you might have already figured out how to get the API Key, but just for new devs..

Its a easy process just register and signin at https://api.tfl.gov.uk/

or at https://api-portal.tfl.gov.uk/

[image]

Then select API credentials and you will be able to see your newly created App ID and App Keys

Answer (score 0):

October 24 2021

It's changed now. They made it way less intuitive, imo

1. The sign up process is about the same,
2. after you need to go to [products](https://api-portal.tfl.gov.uk/products)
3. select `500 requests per minute` (the only public, and costless, option)
4. Choose and enter a name for your subscription

That should redirect you to your profile where you can then find the Primary and Secondary keys.